# intersection observer API and overflow hidden

Tags: css, intersection-observer

I want to load lazily images when I can actually see images.

So, I used intersection observer API. It seems to work fine

But `overflow : hidden` doesn't seem to work with intersection API

'Not Working' means DOM in `overflow: hidden` seems to fire intersection API so that I can't load lazily images

is there anything to do more? or those results are intended?

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Umm. My circumstance is quite tricky. So hard to explain through code
I wanted to answer like yes or no
But if you are hard to answer. Then I will consider explain through the code on this thread or later thread
If you think about me lazy or rude. Sorry, I didn't intended @YashwardhanPauranik

Comment: Intersection observer is triggered also in case when no intersection has occurred, just with property isIntersecting = false.

Comment: it is a problem for me too but only when using IE11 or Edge

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem now, this is how I resolved it:

The IntersectionObserver ***will*** work correctly when ***all of the parents*** have known size. What happened in my case is that I had `<picture>` wrapped in `<div>` but the div didn't have width nor height specified.

As soon as I added `<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">` the images started appearing correctly.